# How to call task properly?

Tags: django, django-celery

I configured django-celery in my application. This is my task:

```
from celery.decorators import task
import simplejson as json
import requests

@task
def call_api(sid):
    try:
        results = requests.put(
            'http://localhost:8000/api/v1/sids/'+str(sid)+"/",
            data={'active': '1'}
        )
        json_response = json.loads(results.text)
    except Exception, e:
        print e
    logger.info('Finished call_api')
```

When I add in my view:

```
call_api.apply_async(
                (instance.service.id,),
                eta=instance.date
            )
```

celeryd shows me:

```
Got task from broker: my_app.tasks.call_api[755d50fd-0f0f-4861-9a18-7f4e4563290a]
Task my_app.tasks.call_api[755d50fd-0f0f-4861-9a18-7f4e4563290a] succeeded in 0.00513911247253s: None
```

so should be good, but nothing happen... There is no call to for example:

```
 http://localhost:8000/api/v1/sids/1/
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Are you running celery as a separate process? 
For example in Ubuntu run using the command 
**sudo python manage.py celeryd**

Till you run celery (or django celery) as a separate process, the jobs will be stored in the database (or queue or the persistent mechanism you have configured - generally in settings.py).